# Picking Values from a List to Update Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

My scenario is like this:

```
pic_from_list = ['best', 'good', 'ok']
dict_list = [{id = "1", food_source : "this food;is;good"}, {id = "2", food_source : "this food;is;ok"}, {id = "3", food_source : "this food is the best"}, {id = "4", food_source : none}, {id = "5", food_source : "no source"}]
```

my code is like this:

```
for item in dict_list:
    idt = item['id']
    #print(idt)

    source = item['source']
    #print(source)
    words = re.split(r'[.|;]+', str(source))
    #print(words)
    class_type = [i.strip() for i in words if i in pic_from_list]
    #print(class_type)

    if len(class_type) ==0:
        if idt not in new_dict.values():
            new_dict.update({'id': idt , 'food_class': 'none'})

            dict_list.append(new_dict)
        else:
            pass
    elif:
if idt not in new_dict.values():
            new_dict.update({'id': idt , 'food_class': 'none'})

            dict_list.append(new_dict)
        else:
            pass
print(dict_list[:4])
```

which giving me wrong input, as in:

```
[{'id':1, food_class:'none'}, {'id':1, food_class:'good'}, {'id':1, food_class:'ok'}..]
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mcve] and explain what you expected instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue. Apparently, i was defining the dictionary outside the loop ! So each time, the code make a loop the dictionary is getting overwritten with no change in the key, but only value. When I defined the dictionary within the loop, it gets started afresh as an empty dictionary, and then the key and value pair has been added to the dictionary.